# How to stop my Feed Back Div to stop changing position with screen resolusion?

Tags: css, html

I have given 2 div's that slides out from the right side of the screen when mouse hovers over it. One div contains an image and the other contains few labels and text boxes.I have pushed both the divs towards the right side so that only the feedback letters from my image is visible. My problem is when the site is viewed in different monitors the div is not where i positioned them earlier. it just moves out in random positions in different monitors. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow-y: hidden">            


   <div id="slideout">![my outer div][1]

      <img src="images/feedback_R.png" height="500px" width="800px" alt="Feedback" >
  <div id="slideout_inner">
     My Content goes here..
        </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS style that i used.

```
<style>
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 1300px;
  z-index: 5000;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}
#slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 180px;
  z-index: 9999 ;
  left: 1400px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
            width: 190px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 6px;
        }
#slideout:hover {
  left: 800px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
  left: 900px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like 'cm' rather than 'px'? I.e specify the actual distance(cm), rather than the number of (variably sized) steps(px).

Comment: @enhzflep I tried to convert all my px into cm ..... its not working as i wanted with screen resolution changed .... previously the screen resolution was around 1366 x 768 it worked well in that resolution , but when i tested it by changing the resolution or zooming the page in or out the entire format of my page changes ....  this is really giving me a big problem . am just a beginner in UI design and this positioning is giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work. I guess it was worth a shot! For what it's worth - I cant think of any sites just now that dont look a bit different when zoomed. They just dont seem to only get larger or smaller, but they always seem to wriggle around a bit too. Zooming, it seems, is treated somewhat differently to different screen resolutions - at least in my limited experience. It must be a common problem! All the best.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you for the effort of giving me an idea about how to go about with ... i will kind of try redoing the entire page with cm instead of px .... and get back to you if it works .... and zooming does cause a little wriggle on the pages ..... mine wriggles too much (sighs)

Answer (score 0):

with px you cannot fix those images to all screen sizes except you use media-queries
or else you can make image with 0 px onload and on hover you can increase to 800px like this:
for ex:
use this style

```
 #slideout {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            z-index: 5000;
            right: 0px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            transition-duration: 0.9s;
        }
  #slideout:hover img{
            width: 100%;
        }

  img{
            width: 0px;
            float: right;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.9s;
            transition-duration: 0.9s;
        }
```

this style increase width of image  to 100% on hover in all screen sizes,if you are ok with this,apply it for feedback content also